# What is file descriptor 10?

Tags: linux, file-descriptors

What is file descriptor 10?

Real-world example (where standard output is ignored, standard error redirected to standard output and data from file descriptor 10 is redirected to standard output) that I have lost the documentation/context for:

```
./cluexec21nodes 'mkdir /home/mortense/sambapub;cd /home/mortense/sambapub;./runcola.sh >/dev/null 2>&1 10>&1 &'
```

The [standard file descriptors are](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor)

```
0   Standard Input (stdin)
1   Standard Output (stdout)
2   Standard Error (stderr)
```

but what is file descriptor 10?

This was used on a Linux system (possibly Red Hat).

Comment: Half of the command doesn't make sense. It attempts to run a script from within a directory which it just `mkdir`'d...

Comment: @grawity: the mkdir, etc. was executed on each of a number nodes in a Linux cluster - the command enclosed in ' s.

Comment: I'm aware of that. I was talking specifically about the `mkdir /home/mortense/sambapub;cd /home/mortense/sambapub;./runcola.sh` part.

Comment: @grawity: yes, you are right. It was not well thought out (probably a mixup of two different stages).

Answer (score 4):

Beyond the standard file descriptors there are 3-1024.  These can be created in scripts with the

```
exec 10<> afilename
```

From this point on, anything written to file descriptor 10 gets written to `afilename`

When you have

```
./script.sh 10>&1
```

You are redirecting anything that would have gone to file descriptor 10 to stdout.

You'll want to review the `runcola.sh` script to see why it is doing this.

Comment: The syntax is `exec 10>afilename` in *sh*.

Comment: @grawity: isn't possible to redirect to another file descriptor in *sh*?

Comment: @Paul: it may have been an arbitrary convention that was used, but given it was used for executing a command on each of a number of nodes in a Linux cluster, couldn't it have something to do with that (network pipes?). Anyway, I will try to find the two scripts.

Comment: @Peter: It is, with `10>&1` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

File descriptors are not fixed; the program may use them in whatever way it wants. (Even fd's 0-2 can be closed, opened, reused.)

In this case, fd 10 seems to be chosen arbitrarily; it could be that `./runcola.sh` expects to be able to write some additional information to it. You'll have to read the script itself to know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Descriptor 10 is used for comments.</s>

Wikipedia has a good starter article at [File descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor).  It's a tiny bit misleading to say that the `sh` syntax "redirects" one descriptor to another.  Solid sources of information may be found in "The Design of the UNIX Operating System".  The documentation for the system calls `dup(2)` and `dup2(2)` reveal a good deal.

[grawity](https://superuser.com/users/1686/grawity), [Paul](https://superuser.com/users/89018/paul), and others (you know who you are) may know of some additional resources, too.  Guys?